# What is the difference between born and borne?

Tags: word-choice, differences

What is the difference between *born* and *borne*. Can anyone cite any solid examples?

Comment: What did the dictionary say?

Comment: @Drew I agree but you might be a little late on this one...

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: Yeah, I knew that. But maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'Born' means to be brought into the world, e.g. as a baby.

> I was born at an early age.

'Borne' is listed in the OED as meaning carried, sustained, or endured. Nowadays it mostly commonly seen in phrases like 'airborne', e.g.

> The virus is airborne.

In the 'endured' sense:

> This terrible customer service cannot be borne!

There is also a similar word, *bourne*: this has a totally different meaning, namely, a small stream.

Comment: "Borne" would be derived from "to bear", I guess.  You bear a physical load literally or an emotional burden figuratively.

Comment: —Usage note 
Since the latter part of the 18th century, a distinction has been made between born  and borne  as past participles of the verb bear 1 . Borne  is the past participle in all senses that do not refer to physical birth: The wheatfields have borne abundantly this year. Judges have always borne a burden of responsibility. Borne  is also the participle when the sense is “to bring forth (young)” and the focus is on the mother rather than on the child. In such cases, borne  is preceded by a form of have  or followed by by: Anna had borne a son the previous year.

Comment: ... and following on:
 Two children borne by her earlier were already grown.  When the focus is on the offspring or on something brought forth as if by birth, born  is the standard spelling, and it occurs only in passive constructions: My friend was born in Ohio. No children have been born at the South Pole. A strange desire was born of the tragic experience. Born  is also an adjective meaning “by birth,” “innate,” or “native”: born free; a born troublemaker; Mexican-born.

Comment: How about this: "NewACME inc. is a company *born* out of the ACME Federation of Widget Makers."  Should that be born or borne?

Comment: Born, because you have used 'out of'. Borne is used in a mother/offspring context because the mother 'bears the burden' of the child.

Answer (score 6):

They are both past participles of *to bear*. However, according to, for example, [this source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bear):

> Thanks to the vagaries of English spelling, bear has two past participles: *born* and *borne*. Traditionally, born is used only in passive constructions referring to birth: *I was born in Chicago*. For all other uses, including active constructions referring to birth, *borne* is the standard form: *She has borne both her children at home*. *I have borne his insolence with the patience of a saint*.